# jquery password validation not working as expected

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, passwords

i'm having the following validation code:

```
function validPassword(password)
{
    var regex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#-?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#-?&]{8,}$/;
    var valid = regex.test(password);
    return valid;
}
```

the requirements are:
minimum length 8 characters, 1 special character, 1 alphabetic character, 1 number minimum.

i'm not familiar with regex, however, the validation doesn't work with `12345678a` - for some reason detecting a special character doesn't work .. 
any ideas? thanks

Comment: You need to escape special characters than have semantic meaning, in this case `-` in the special char part (probably others)

Comment: Change the dash in the middle: https://regex101.com/r/gE6yM7/2

Comment: Also, why double `$`? Where do you get this regex from? I have seen many questions with the same double `$` in them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is presence of **unescaped hyphen** in the middle of character class that acts as range between preceding and following character.

You can use this regex to fix it:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&-])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&-]{8,}$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP5qG8/4)

Note how hyphen is placed at the end of character class in lookahead and in the match now.

You can also place unescaped hyphen at start.